# General Solution of the differential equation $(xy+2(x^2)(y^2))ydx + (xy-(x^2)(y^2))xdy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried it by seperating the terms but the term with $2(x^2)(y^2)$ is giving me problem because i do not know what to do with that $2$ otherwise all terms are getting solved in basic forms .

Comment: $y(x)=0$ is one solution

Comment: The technique used in the answer below is called finding an "integrating factor". Is there anything about it in your notes?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice the equation can be made exact. Since
$$ \underbrace{(xy^2 +2 x^2 y^3 )}_{M} dx + \underbrace{( x^2y - x^3 y^2) }_{N}dy = 0 $$
$$M_y = 2 xy + 6 x^2 y^2 \quad \& \quad N_x = 2 xy - 3 x^2 y^2 $$
multiply the equation by
$$ \mu(xy) = \exp \int  \frac{ M_y - N_x }{y N - x M} d(xy)= \exp \int  -\frac{ 3 }{xy} d(xy)= \frac{1}{x^3y^3}$$
you'll find the equation will then be exact. note the integration is with respect to the variable $v = xy$

Comment: You wrote wrong $N$

Comment: You can simplify first when xy not zero. The A. by Jeb is to basically to substitute y=z/x.

Comment: Just fixed the typo, the technique still holds.